# Magnolia CMS's built-in Form: SMTP configuration overriding "From" input

Tags: magnolia

On the following page http://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/modules/mail.html#ConfiguringSMTP
In the section "Sending messages >> Plain text and HTML messages", we can read:

From:[...]Regardless of the address entered here, Magnolia CMS will use the smtpUser to send the email but the address here is displayed as the sender to the recipient. This means you can send an email from fake@address.com and it will appear to come from this address

However, when I receive the email I can still see the smtpUser config's email and my "fake@address.com" email address is not displayed (it is ignored!?)

Am I missing something? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this on the demo site at http://demoauthor.magnolia-cms.com/demo-project/service/contact.html and it seemed to work as expected.

Are you using a fresh install of Magnolia 4.4.5? Could you verify that you're hitting the "Edit Form Settings" button on the page, going to the "E-Mail" tab, and entering "fake@address.com" into the From field there? If you're then trying the form on a public instance, you'll need to be sure that the form page has been activated so that the public version of it has your "From" setting as well.